# Is it possible to run splunk on port 443 without NGinx?

Tags: splunk

Is there any way to run Splunk enterprise on port 443 without NGinx.

I am getting in issue when triggering alert it redirects to different domains &port.

If any possibility is there , please share steps .

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to start splunk on different port is to execute command:

```
$SPLUNK_HOME/bin/splunk set web-port 8081
```

But you can also edit file `$SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/web.conf` (create it if doesn't exist)
and add/edit this section:

```
[settings]
httpport = 443
```

Then restart the splunk. BTW you need to restart it as `root` which can mess some things. This is required because you want `splunk` to listen to privileged port.